# running a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit machine

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

What are the implications if we are running a 32 binary on 64 bit machine.Will it have any impact if machine has more than 4 GB of RAM(the RAM in the system is 8GB)?

Comment: Would the answer "No" be sufficient?

Comment: If by impact you mean positive impact, then in a way: more RAM means more disk cache...

Answer (score 5):

When running 32bit binaries on 64bit machines (assuming the OS is running in 64bit mode), you have the following limitations:

1. The binary cannot take advantage of 64bit arithmetic instructions. This might reduce performance.
2. The binary cannot address more than 4GB of virtual memory.

However, these 4GB can be located anywhere inside your 8GB of RAM. So if you are running many 32bit applications, each using less than 4GB, you do take advantage of all your 8GB of RAM.

Note that, due to various limitations, your application might actually only be able to allocate 2GB of virtual memory.

Comment: Point no. 1 (The binary cannot take advantage of 64bit arithmetic instructions) is false for at least two platforms. (sparcv9-linux/solaris and [x32-*-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI))

Comment: On x64, 32bit binaries cannot access the upper 32 bits of the [General-Purpose Registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X64#Operating_modes). Therefore, when adding two 64bit numbers, a 32bit binary would have to issue two instructions instead of one. @jørgensen

Comment: x86-64 adds many more things: more registers, PIC-relative addressing, a saner ABI using registers for function calls, resulting typically in performance improvements that offset significantly offset the performance decrease implicit in using bigger (more cache-unfriendly) types. In other platforms (sparc64 vs sparc? mips64 vs mips?) going from 32-bit to 64-bit may actually decrease performance.